# Self Load testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-testing

We have recently moved our java struts2 webapplication to AWS elastic beanstalk, which has Elastic load balancing, Auto-scaling etc., We want to check the load performance with autoscaling feature so as to ensure zero downtime site, currently i set the minimum instance count as 2 and maximum instance count as 4 for autoscaling. Can you please tell me some self load testing websites to test my site or a script which adds load to the site and scale the instances to maximum count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user-friendly solution, you should check out [BrowserMob](https://browsermob.com/website-load-testing).

You provide Selenium scripts (WebDriver or RC) to simulate users and then schedule a test (via the BrowserMob website).  Then BrowserMob provisions EC2 machines to run your Selenium tests against your web application and provides real-time response-time and traffic statistics.

It's not free, but very cheap for low numbers of users (e.g., 25 users for an hour works out about USD 3.50).

Comment: thanx for the info shamp00....   any opensource load testing tools that you recommend?

Comment: There are some suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website).